# How to create a custom validator in Angular 7 that checks if the username exists in the db?

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to create a custom validator that tells me if the username I wrote in the form input is in the database or not.
I have a component called Login, and in the "login.page.ts" I created a FormGroup:

```
constructor(
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private service: ClientsService
  ) {

    this.formLogin = new FormGroup(
      {
        username: new FormControl('', Validators.compose(
          [
            Validators.required,
            this.UsernameValidator
          ]
        )
    ),
        password: new FormControl('', Validators.compose(
          [
            Validators.required,
          ]
        ) )
      }
    );
   }
```

```
 DoesUserExists(username)
  {
    return this.service.doesUserExists(username);
  }
```

I have a service that makes a post request to the server:

```
  doesUserExists(username: string)
  {
    console.log(username);

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };

    var usernameJson = {
      "username" : username
    };

    var success = false;

    return this.http.post('someURL', usernameJson, httpOptions)
    .subscribe(data => 
    {
      console.log("data"  + JSON.stringify(data));
      success = true;
    },
    error => 
    {
      console.log("error" + JSON.stringify(error));
    })
    // .toPromise()
    // .then(res => {
    //   console.log(res);
    //   return res;
    // })
    // .catch(error => { 
    //   return error.status === 404 ?  false:  true
    // });


    return success;
  }
```

and I tried creating the validator:

```
  UsernameValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key : string] : boolean } | null 
  {
    if (this.DoesUserExists(control.value)) 
    {
      return { 'username' : true};
    }
    return null;
  }
```

The problem is I get an **error** that I am not sure how to fix:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'DoesUserExists' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'DoesUserExists' of undefined
```

Anyone knows how to fix those uncaught errors in the promise? :(
Or a better idea for creating a custom validator for validating the username from the db?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55279113/angular-7-custom-async-validator) helps.